# Math writing solutions

Tags: soft-question, advice, learning

I will begin to learn in the university next month and I would like to know what is the best way to write math except from handwriting? I am not sure if to use a mathematical software, digital pen or tablet.

My writing is unclear and unorganized, and I usually lose things like notebooks so I think it would be better if everything would be on a computer or a tablet.

i.e I need a comfortable technology that will allow easy writing of math in the university.

Please people who used such technology, reply and express how it was, and what kind of technology did you use during the time you wrote math in the university.

Comment: What I did in my first semester in university was: I took notes in class and then copied them neatly and thoroughly to my notebook at home. Yes, it took time...but it really helped to understand and assimilate things better. I stopped this masochist habit during second semester or so.

Comment: As a math instructor, what's best for *me* is that people write clearly, linearly & in a composed, well-organized manner. That's *also best for you* - grade-wise, of course, but not only. As DonAntonio pointed out, making the passage from chaotic to organized writing will affect your cognition positively & help bring yourself up to university standards. Organizing your thoughts is far more important than tablet vs paper. Solutions to your Calculus problems will have a short life-span, irrespectively of whether they are typed-in or not; organized thinking will last forever :). Best of luck!

Comment: At some point, I started the habit of submitting my exercises in TeX. That was nice and fun and helped me train TeX and helped my prof read my ideas (and as a sidenote, I think that people are more likely to miss minor errors in nicely typeset texts than in hardly legible scribbling). *However*, I think anything but handwriting is unsuitable during lectures (think speed) and also there is a lot of distraction from tha subject if you maybe spend more time coping with TeX than with the math.

Comment: A bit OT I might add that one of my first year profs had invented the unified letter, as we students used to joke - that is $i,j,\iota,l,r,n,v$ all looked more or less the same on the blackboard. I think this show that *everyone* should train to wite reasonably legible even under speed pressure ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I guess every prof does either that, or tends to write books on the blackboard ^^

Comment: I have never tried [livetexing](http://www.google.com/search?q=livetexing), but some people say they were using it. See also [this MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12638/taking-lecture-notes-in-lectures/12673#12673).

Comment: See also [What software and/or language to use to take Math lecture notes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17805/what-software-and-or-language-to-use-to-take-math-lecture-notes) and [Best software to take math notes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/best-software-to-take-math-notes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the variant of $\LaTeX$ known as
MathJax, which is used on this site.

For working offline,
I use qute, available for
Mac and Windows here:
http://www.inkcode.net/qute

I have developed techniques
for using qute in real-time
for entering my math.
Here are some of them:

If you enter an invalid formula,
qute will *not* display it.
So, when entering an expression
that needs to be complete,
I enter the frame first,
then fill it in.
For example,
to enter a fraction,
I first enter
"\frac{}{}"
and then fill in the
numerator and denominator.

I work in split-screen mode,
so I always see both the
input and the displayed math.

Since qute formats its input
one paragraph at a time,
remember that
Enter starts a new paragraph
and shift-enter starts a new line
in the current paragraph.
Also remember that
up and down arrow keys do *not*
go beyond the current paragraph.

Always save your work
(cmd-s on the Mac)
after every moderate change.
If you start a new file,
whatever you have been working on
will be lost if it has not been saved.

I save my work in a 
Dropbox directory
so I can access it anywhere.

The author of qute is
quite responsive to questions,
so if you have any problems or questions,
ask.

If I am working on a problem
for this site,
I create it in qute,
save it,
and then use the
"Publish" option
to copy it to the clipboard.
I then paste it
into the answer (or comment) box.

Feel free to ask any me questions
as comments on this answer.
I will do my best to answer them.
You can also email me at
mjcohen@acm.org,
but my answers here will be seen
by more people.